# Validate the list elements in evaluateJsonPath in apache nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

Using apache nifi, I want to get the all the input twitter files which have the hashtags for "tech" 
The input json is

```
{
  "created_at": "Sun Mar 25 18:00:43 +0000 2018",
  "id": 977968537028481025,
  "id_str": "977968537028481025",
  "text": "@bby__nim You know like datttt",
  "entities": {
    "hashtags": [
      {
        "text": "tech",
        "indices": [
          12,
          17
        ]
      },
      {
        "text": "BusinessPlan",
        "indices": [
          48,
          61
        ]
      }
    ],
    "urls": [

    ],
    "user_mentions": [
      {
        "screen_name": "bby__nim",
        "name": "bbynim\ud83d\udc7d",
        "id": 424356807,
        "id_str": "424356807",
        "indices": [
          0,
          9
        ]
      }
    ],
    "symbols": [

    ]
  },
  "favorited": false,
  "retweeted": false,
  "filter_level": "low",
  "lang": "en",
  "timestamp_ms": "1522000843661"
}
```

1. Under `EvaulateJsonPath`, validating whether the hashtags is present or not using `$.{entities.hashtags:jsonPath('$[0]')}`, which is successfully validating
2. But in `RouteOnAttribute`, can someone tell me how to validate whether the `entities.hashtags` has the value called `tech`?

Answer (score 1):

Use the evaluate json path processor configs as shown below, 
[image]
Now we are extracting all the **text values** from the **hashtags array** and keeping as flowfile attribute.
In addition you have to change the properties **Destination** to **flowfile-attribute** and **Return Type** as **Json**

[image]
Now we are having all the text values in an array then use **RouteOnAttribute** processor to validate the **entities.hastags** attribute having a **tech** value in it (or) not.

***RouteOnAttribute configs:-***
[image]
Add a new property as

contains tech

```
${entities.hashtags:contains("tech")} //checks as sub string if the array having tech
```

We are using contains function in our expression language will evaluate the array having tech substring in it or not.

But we need to check the **values in the array** so use the below expression language for that

**contains tech**

```
${anyDelineatedValue("${entities.hashtags:replace('[',''):replace(']','')}",","):equals('"tech"')} //checks values in the array
```

we are using anyDelineatedValue,replace,equals functions in our expression language will evaluate the array having tech values in it or not.

In addition if you want to check the first text value in hashtags array then your evaluatejson path would be
**entities.hashtags**

```
$.entities.hashtags[0].text
```

Comment: Below is my evaulatejsonpath: 

`Destination --> flowfile-attribute`
`Return Type --> json`
`Path Not Found Behavior --> ignore`
`Null Value Representation --> empty string`
`entities.hashtags -->  $.{entities.hashtags[*].text}`

RouteOnAttribute:

`Routing Strategy -->  Route to Property name`
`entities.hashtags -->  ${entities.hashtags:contains("tech")}`

Still the files are going to unmatched folder

Comment: Could you please remove curly braces in evaluate json path processor i.e **entities.hashtags --> $.entities.hashtags[*].text**